# jQuery hover not working

Tags: jquery, hover

When I try this.

```
<ul id="sub_navigation"><li>A</li><li>B</li></ul>
```

with jQuery hover like this

```
$(function() {
    $('#sub_navigation').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    },
    function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    });

   alert($('#sub_navigation').is('.hovered'));

});
```

always return false when I hover at sub_navigation.

there is something wrong?

thanks

Comment: You are doing the `alert` before you even have the chance of moving the mouse upon the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning false is normal here, since you're alerting *when the page loads*, instead of *when you hover*.  For example this would return `true`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#sub_navigation').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
        alert($('#sub_navigation').is('.hovered'));
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    });
});
```

[You can test it here](http://true).

---

Keep in mind though, if you're doing this just for styling, using the `:hover` CSS pseudo-class will work in all browsers except IE6 here (with no JavaScript):

```
#sub_navigation:hover { color: red; }
```

[Test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/naWgy/1/).